# Ajax sourced dataTable is not sorting, searching, or paging the data.

Tags: jquery, datatable

Ajax sourced dataTable is not sorting, searching, or paging the data. 
because of 'iTotalRecords', it shows 5 pages in the footer, but all of the data is actually displayed in one page.

JSON: `{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":44,"iTotalDisplayRecords":44,"aaData":[{"one":"--qqqq","two":"--yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"----qqqq","two":"----yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"qqqq","two":"yyyy"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"},{"one":"tttttt","two":"iiiiii"}]}`

`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testtable").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/api/test',
            "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "one", "sType": "text", "bSortable": true, "bUseRendered": false },

            ],

        });
    });
</script>

<table id="testtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>one1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

`

Comment: API went through major change as of version 1.10. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.10.2 and jquery 1.11.1

Comment: options are different in newer version. It looks like you are using setup for older one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  charlietfl, I found the correct setup.

`$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#testtable").dataTable({
                "ajax":'/api/test',
                "columns": [
                    {"data":"one"}
                ]
            });
        });`

I had tried a similar setup, but without the "columns" property.
In dataTable official examples, they had a very similar ajax data and table and their example didn't include "columns", but a different example of theirs did.